# Meaning / use of "belongs elsewhere" for closing questions

Tags: discussion, migration, close-reasons

An option given as a reason to close a question is that the question belongs elsewhere. When you select that, you are given only one choice (which you have to select), namely that it belongs on linguistic meta – which it usually doesn't. There is no option to specifically say that the question belongs on ELL, Philosophy, or whatever. Does this mean that we should just suggest that such questions go to meta and let the mods sort it out? This seems like a pretty dysfunctional (mis-informative) option.

Answer (score 4):

I think the option is restricted to moderators. If you notice a question that deserves to be migrated, you can flag the question for moderator attention, choose the **custom** option and then concisely explain where you think it should go and why.

I guess that's the only way to do it.

Comment: The mods can ask for sites to be listed there, but we'd need to show that enough migrations take place and that this community understands the scope of the other site. This site is so slow that it really isn't needed.